# Where is virtualenvwrapper.sh after pip install?

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, pip, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to setup virtualenvwrapper on OSX, and all the instructions and tutorials I've found tell me to add a source command to .profile, pointing towards virtualenvwrapper.sh. I've checked all the python and site-packages directories, and I can't find any virtualenvwrapper.sh. Is this something I need to download separately? Is pip not installing correctly?

This is the contents of /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper:

```
hook_loader.py      hook_loader.pyc     project.py      project.pyc     user_scripts.py     user_scripts.pyc
```

As you can see, no virtualenvwrapper.sh. Where is it?

Comment: For me, since I used `pyenv global 3.9.1` to set my default system python before running `pip install virtualenvwrapper`, the file ended up getting installed at `~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`. Hope that helps anyone else using pyenv!

Answer (score 187, accepted):

You can use the `find` command to search for a file:

`find / -name virtualenvwrapper.sh`

This will search all directories from the root for the file.

---

on ubuntu 12.04 LTS, installing through pip, it is installed to

`/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

---

on ubuntu 17.04, installing through pip as a normal user, it is installed to

`~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.10, it is also installed in `~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, it is installed in ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

Answer (score 106):

did you already try this ?

```
$ which virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: this works, but why doesn't `which virtualenvwrapper` work? Isn't that the name of the command in the environmental variables?

Comment: To help anybody else asking this same question about why `which` doesn't work, it's because virtualenvwrapper is actually using its custom bash completion file to add purely virtual commands, of which the common `virtualenvwrapper` command is one.  Consequently, there is no physical file on the drive for `which` to point to.

Comment: @yourfriendzak, the bash script `virtualenvwrapper.sh` needs to be sourced in your shell before any of the commands (`mkvirtualenv`, `rmvirtualenv`, etc.) are available, i.e. 

`$ source /path/to/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

Comment: This was much faster than `find` but both worked. Mine was located in       `usr/local/bin` on OS X.

Answer (score 76):

The exact path where      **virtualenvwrapper.sh**         *is stored/located varies from OS to OS*. Even with in same OS, it varies from *version to version.* So we need a generic solution that works for all OS versions.

*Easiest way I have found to find its path is*: Do

```
pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper
```

This will prompt a confirmation. Say "No"
But first line of confirmation shows the path of virtualenvwrapper.sh (Prompt gives a list of files it will delete, if you say Yes. First entry in this list contains path to virtualenvwrapper.sh in your machine)

Comment: It didn't work for me. I'm using Python 2.7.14 with Virtualenv 15.1.0 , virtualenvwrapper 4.8.2.

Comment: @whyisyoung : seriously? can you send me the screen shot right after you run "pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper"

Comment: Nice shortcut. I am using this even for other libraries. Thank!

Answer (score 58):

I just reinstalled it with pip.

```
sudo pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

And this time it put it in /usr/local/bin.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu, also allowing `which virtualenvwrapper.sh` to work, which had been returning nothing until I did this.

Comment: After this command on Fedora 23 I have found virtualenvwrapper.sh only in usr/bin .

Comment: Had initially installed it with `apt-get` and it landed in `/usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh`, then purged it and did your trick.

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 14.04 if you `find / -name xxxx.sh` didn't find anything.

Answer (score 15):

or, like I did..just uninstall virtualenvwrapper

> sudo pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper

and then install it with easy_install

> sudo easy_install virtualenvwrapper

this time I found the file "**/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh**" installed... Before that I weren't finding that file anywhere even by this command

> find / -name virtualenvwrapper.sh

Answer (score 12):

On Mac OS

```
which virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

u got

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

and u can

```
sudo ln /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

and in your `.bash_profile`

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

**or** u can

```
source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Answer (score 9):

In OSx EI captain, I installed the virtualenvwrapper as

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
```

, however I cannot find the virtualenvwrapper.sh in `/user/local/bin`,
it was finally found at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` , and you can make an soft link to /usr/local/bin as

`ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh  /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`, and everything you can just follow the setup guide as the official document does. 
Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

In OS X 10.8.2, with Python 2.7:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

Answer (score 5):

For me it was in :

```
~/Library/Python/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

(With OS X, with a `pip install --user` installation)

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem. If you have older version of virtualenvwrapper, then pip wont work.

download src from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper/3.6
and python setup.py install. Then the problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

For RPM-based distributions(like Fedora 19), after running the `sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper` command, you may find the file at:

```
/usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: On Manjaro, arch based, it was also located under `/usr/bin` instead of  `/usr/local/bin`. I don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

Installed it using pip on Ubuntu 15.10 using a normal user, it was put in `~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` which I found by running:

`$ find / -name virtualenvwrapper.sh 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
find / -name virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

I got a TON of "permissions denied"s, and exactly one printout of the file location. I missed it until I found that file location when I uninstall/installed it again with pip.

In case you were curious, it was in

```
/usr/local/share/python/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: to get rid of 'permission denied' you can redirect STDERR to /dev/null. For example:  $ find / -name virtualenvwrapper.sh 2>/dev/null

Answer (score 2):

In my case (OSX El Capitan, version 10.11.5) I needed to edit the .profile like so:

In the terminal:

> vim ~/.profile

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export MSYS_HOME=C:\msys\1.0
source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

And then reload the profile (that it will be availuble in the current session.)

> source ~/.profile

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

```
/usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

I've installed it on Ubuntu 16.04 and it resulted in this location.

Comment: This happened for me too. :(

Comment: Same for ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2):

I can find one in macOS Mojave (10.14) while playing with virtualenvwrapper-4.8.4

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

Answer (score 2):

If you use brew on Mac you can find it at

`/opt/homebrew/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an OS X question, here's what worked for me on Linux (Red Hat).

My virtualwrapper.sh was in

```
~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

This is probably because I installed virtualenvwrapper locally, using the `--user` flag...

```
pip install --user virtualenvwrapper
```

...as an alternative to the [risky practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055859/what-are-the-risks-of-running-sudo-pip) of using `sudo pip`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: `No such file or directory` I also browsed the /usr/local/bin directory and couldn't find anything that looked related to virtualenv or virtualenvwrapper

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in with the beagle bone black(debian).

Manually downloading the package and installing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**For Ubuntu**
If you just installed it, check the output on Terminal, I'm posting mine :

```
Running setup.py install for virtualenv-clone    
Installing virtualenv-clone script to /home/username/.local/bin
Successfully installed virtualenvwrapper virtualenv virtualenv-clone stevedore pbr six
Cleaning up...
```

Here the second line tells you the path. For me it was at `/home/username/.local/bin`

Answer (score 0):

pip will not try to make things difficult for you on purpose.

The thing is commands based files are always installed in `/bin` folders they can be anywhere on the system path.

I had the same problem and I found that I have these files in my

`~/.local/bin/`

folder instead of

`/usr/loca/bin/`

which is the common case, but I think they changed the default path to

`~` or $HOME

directory because its more isolate for the pip installations and provides a distinction between apt-get packages and pip packages.

So coming to the point you have two choices here either you go to your
***.bashrc*** and make changes like this

```
# for virtualenv wrapper
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/Envs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source $HOME/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

and than create a directory **virtualenvwrapper** under
`/usr/share/` and than symlink your **virtualwrapper_lazy.sh** like this

```
sudo ln -s ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh
```

and you can check if your **workon** command is working which will list your existing virtualenv's.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute `pip install virtualenvwrapper` without sudo as a normal user **pip will run but won't copy the files in the required locations** because the lack of permissions.

```
mortiz@florida:~# sudo pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
```

Use sudo and the files will be created under their respective paths:

```
root@florida:/usr/local/bin# ls -ltr
total 8008
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff 8136192 Jun 11 17:45 chromedriver
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff   41697 Sep  5 16:06 virtualenvwrapper.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff    2210 Sep  5 16:06 virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff     215 Sep  5 16:06 pbr
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff     218 Sep  5 16:06 virtualenv-clone
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff     213 Sep  5 16:06 virtualenv
root@florida:/usr/local/bin#
```

Worked for me on Debian GNU/Linux 9

Answer (score -1):

in my case: /home/username/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

Answer (score -2):

Have you installed it using sudo?
Was the error in my case.