# Is it okay to relocate packages from ./Library/Python/2.7/lib to /usr/local/lib?

Tags: python, bash, macos

So I'm trying to install *virtualenvwrapper* and then as a requirement for the task I'm trying to implement I'm supposed to update my .bash_profile file to contain the lines

> source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

But after activating the changes to the file I get

> -bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory

So that's because using *pip install virtualenv* the package gets installed in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages .

My question is, is it okay to manually relocate the packages? What would be the way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the path in your source command to match the location of the script, which should be where pip installed it, that is in `/usr/local/bin` if you used `sudo pip install` to install it system wide, or wherever the bin directory associated with your python environment is located. That would `/path/to/virtualenv/local/bin` if you are using a virtualenv, or `/path/to/anaconda/bin` if you are using anaconda's python distribution.

Comment: This happened. `/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory`

Comment: Any idea how to find out where this virtualenvwrapper.sh file may be?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647266/where-is-virtualenvwrapper-sh-after-pip-install found this. okay.

Comment: For me it ends up in ```/usr/local/bin``` and the corresponding location when using anaconda (```path/to/anaconda/bin/```)

Comment: using _pip install_ the file was not found anywhere in the system, using sudo worked for me and put it in `usr/local/bin` but I'd like to avoid using it. Well. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If you don't want to use system wide library, you can use a virtualenv, activate it, and when pip install virtualenvwrapper, you will find virtualenvwrapper.sh in ```/path/to/virtualenv/local/bin```, so you don't have to use superuser privileges.

Comment: There is a difference between `./Libray/Python...` (which is a relative path, probably referring to the user's personal `Library` folder, i.e., `/Users/momo/Library/Python/...`) and `/Library/Python/...`, which is a global path usable by all users.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I didn't really pay attention to that since, the problem doesn't seem to be where the librairies are installed, rather where corresponding binaries are. I've edited my answer, I hope it makes this clearer.